# Setting the content size of my UIScrollView in viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear has no effect - why?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview

I'm trying to force the content size of my `UIScrollVIew` when it's container loads. I'm finding this much more difficult than I'd imagine it would be. I've tried setting the content size in both `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`, like so:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{    
    CGSize newContentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.contentSize.width, scrollView.frame.size.height + 80.0);
    [scrollView setContentSize:newContentSize];    
}
```

If I place a breakpoint right after I call `setContentSize`, I can see that the new content size is indeed what I set it to.

However, if I then check the content size at some arbitrary point after `viewWillAppear`, such as, say, `scrollViewDidScroll`, the content size has reverted back to the size of the "actual" content in the scroll view, and not the size I tried forcing it to be in `viewDidAppear`.

Why is this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have no idea what is resetting it on you, but I can help you find the answer.

What I usually do in a situation like this is subclass UIScrollView (usually as "XXXUIScrollView"), override `setContentSize:` (to just call `[super setContentSize:size]`, maybe with an NSLog), and set a breakpoint in the overridden method to see what is setting the value.

Comment: Good idea - I'll give that a try and see who the guilty party is.

Comment: Well, what was it, @unforgiven3?

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same problem and the only workaround I found so far was to do performSelector:withObject:afterDelay - to set the contentSize property after some small delay:
[UIScrollView won't scroll even when I set content size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178789/uiscrollview-wont-scroll-even-when-i-set-content-size/13381899#13381899)